# Encryption file with Arduino

Tags: encryption, arduino

If I have an Arduino Zero (with two USB ports), can I make something like this:

-to one USB port I connect pendrive

-the second USB port I connect with PC

-when I move file from PC to pendrive, the file will be encrypted "inside" Arduino(I want to create my own algorithm to this)

-only way to decrypt file it will be connect pendrive to USB port in Arduino and move back to PC.

Is this possible?

Comment: you can't. on the native USB port maybe you could simulate a mass storage device. but you can't do anything with the programming port. and to connect the pendrive you would need the arduino to be USB host for a mass storage device

Comment: @Juraj And if I added additional USB port to Arduino - it will works?

Comment: an USB host shield would help. but I don't know if an arduino library to read a mass storage device exists. I saw somewhere a library to simulate an USB mass storage device type.

Comment: https://github.com/markmal/MSD

Comment: https://github.com/felis/USB_Host_Shield_2.0/tree/06d5ed134a37e22575c0ce18c061d9ef115151e0/examples/testusbhostFAT